# VBA macro to create a list of all URLs connected with one google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure if anyone knows how to do this but could really do with your help,
I have a google sheet that contains 4 or 5 sheets at the moment and that number will increase as we go on,
I have a fantastic piece of code I found that can pull in the data from a Google Sheet Tab using the URL,
however it only does the one tab,
so I was wondering if anyone knows a way to create a list of all the tabs in a google sheets URL's

here is a URL to the first sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G-2PJHClHmI0hrYsV1QxNDzyXG0Kze0IIxzb_n3n6oQ/edit#gid=303111374

so I need a way to go to this then import the URLs for all other sheets

please help if you can, any ideas would be great, also if you have a better way to pull all sheets into excel I'm all ears.

Comment: Please create a [reprex] with the code you are using.

Comment: share that fantastic code